# How to add NETWORK SERVICE to Users permission group?

Tags: iis, permissions, .net

I'm adapting an application from a different server, their installation guide tells me to

> Add Server Name\Network Service identity to Users permission group.

So how can I?

I've tried:

- Via Computer Management, Groups, Users and adding it there, but it wasn't found (neither netname\NETWORK SERVICE nor BY AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE).

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. From Administrative Tools > Computer Management, expand System Tools > Local Users and Groups > Groups.
2. Double-click the Users group and click Add.  Click Locations and select your computer node.
3. Now:

   1. Type `Network Service` into the 'Enter the object names' *OR*
   2. Click Advanced, then Find Now and select it from the Search Results.

Comment: Thank you! That worked! The location part is what I was missing.

Comment: NB: Also ensure that `Object Types` lists `Built-in security principals`

Comment: How do I do the reverse, ie find out which groups NETWORK Service is in?

Comment: @OldGeezer Local or Domain groups?

Comment: Local machine is good enough.

Comment: @OldGeezer - at a push, perhaps PowerShell `Get-LocalGroup | %{ $g = $_; Get-LocalGroupMember -Group $g | ?{ $_.Name -eq 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' } | %{ Write-Output $g } }` gets you close (but a separate question might yield better results)

Comment: @OldGeezer - For domain groups, similar `Get-ADGroup -Filter * | %{ $g = $_; Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $g | ?{ $_.Name -eq $env:COMPUTERNAME } | %{ Write-Output $g } }` might be there...